# Rearrange a table for usability on mobile in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I apologize in advance if this sounds a bit rambling as I am new to web development and unsure how to describe what I'm looking for. Basically, I have a table which I am using to display my various lab projects for my internet software course. Currently there are 4 columns and 3 rows, and it works fine on desktop. However, when viewed on mobile, all the cells become squished to the point they're unreadable. Ultimately I would like the table to rearrange itself as the screen size becomes smaller. For instance, if the screen is half as wide then the table becomes 2 columns wide and 6 rows high. I have looked into the `@media` rule in CSS, but I am unsure how to achieve my goal without actually editing the HTML itself.

[This](http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2375a08/) is the actual website as it sits. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code for the table:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan="4"><h1>Labs</h1></th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="window.location.href='lab1/lab1.html'" style="background-image: url(images/survey_snip.PNG);background-position: top;background-size: 140%;">
            <h3 class="label">Lab 1</h3>
            <p class="description">This lab is a customer satisfaction survey for a fictional car dealership.</p>
        </td>
        <td onclick="window.location.href='lab2/lab2a.html'" style="background-image: url(images/table_snip.PNG);background-position: top;background-size: 140%;">
            <h3 class="label">Lab 2 (Part A)</h3>
            <p class="description">This lab is a table which lists the first ten presidents, their birthplaces, and years in office.</p>
        </td>
        <td onclick="window.location.href='lab2/lab2b.html'" style="background-image: url(images/survey_snip.PNG);background-position: top;background-size: 140%;">
            <h3 class="label">Lab 2 (Part B)</h3>
            <p class="description">This lab is a continuation of Lab 1 with CSS added.</p>
        </td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
        <td><h3 class="label">Coming Soon</h3></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the pertinent portion of the css:

```
td
{
border: 3px solid black;
border-radius: 50px;
text-align: center;
align-content: center;
width: 25%; 
min-width: 250px;
height: 33.3%;
vertical-align: text-top;
margin: auto;
}

td:hover
{
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px lightblue, 0px -4px 2px lightblue, 4px 0px 2px 
lightblue, -4px 0px 2px lightblue;
}

table
{
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 95%;
min-height: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
border-spacing: 10px;
table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Try using tablesaw.

https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!